# Libgdx and Bluetooth

Tags: libgdx

I am looking into pairing two devices for a game using blutooth along with LibGdx and everything I have found so far doesn't explain well and is incomplete. Any one have any good sources of a game that uses such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific support in Libgdx for Bluetooth, so you'll just have to use whatever the platform provides (presumably you're focused on the Android backend?).

Once you've figured out the platform's APIs, you'll want to use an approach like the following to access it: http://siondream.com/blog/games/abstracting-platform-specific-code-in-libgdx/